# How to triplicate specific items in an array for javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to only triplicate certain elements in an array? I want to triplicate the "3" in the array only.
For instance:
const deck = [1, 3, 9, 3, 7];
should become [1, 3, 3, 3, 9, 3, 3, 3, 7]

I have tried the method below, deck is the random array:

```
var i;
  for (let i=0;i<deck.length;i++){
    if (deck[i]==3){
      return deck.flatMap(x=>[x,x,x]);
    }else return deck[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: please include what have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function that uses `flatMap()` to map over the array and triplicate the specific values.

```js
const deck = [1, 3, 9, 3, 7];

const triplicate = (number, arr) => {
  return arr.flatMap(x => x === number ? [x, x, x]: x);
}

console.log(triplicate(3, deck));
```

Comment: @CLHE this function returns an array, are you doing something else with the outcome of this function?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const triplicate = (arr = [], number) => 
  arr.flatMap(n => n === number ? [n, n, n] : n);

console.log( triplicate([1, 3, 9, 3, 7], 3) );
```